# Find a sequence of system linearly indepedent vectors converging to given linearly depend one

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that  $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a linearly dependent system of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

How to construct sequences of vectors  $(u_{1k}),\ldots,(u_{2k})$ in $\mathbb R^n$ s.t. $u_{1n}\rightarrow v_1,\ldots,u_{nk} \rightarrow v_n$, as $k\rightarrow \infty$, and such that for each $k\in \mathbb N$ vectors $u_{1k},\ldots,u_{nk}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Let $u_{jk} = v_j$.

Comment: $v_j$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Sorry, missed that

Comment: use orthogonal vectors to complete the base of $v_i$ and move outside the span of $v_j$